# Laravel add extra data to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have my data like:

```
data: [,…]
    0: {name: "Product One", price: "15000", quantity: 2, attributes: {attr: {name: "weight", value: "35"}},…}
        attributes: {attr: {name: "weight", value: "35"}}
        conditions: [{name: "blue", value: 0}, {name: "L", value: 0}]
        name: "Product One"
        price: "15000"
        quantity: 2
```

I need to add `id` into each array of my data like:

```
data: [,…]
    0: {name: "Product One", price: "15000", quantity: 2, attributes: {attr: {name: "weight", value: "35"}},…}
        attributes: {attr: {name: "weight", value: "35"}}
        conditions: [{name: "blue", value: 0}, {name: "L", value: 0}]
        name: "Product One"
        price: "15000"
        quantity: 2
        id: 10 // added id
```

## Screenshot

Here is how my database looks like:

[image: one]

## Code

Currently just getting my `cart_data` column, need to add column `id` as well.

```
$items2 = CartStorage::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

$items = [];
foreach($items2 as $item){
  $items[] = json_decode($item['cart_data']); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be by creating a var and add it there like so:

```php
$items2 = CartStorage::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

$items = [];
foreach($items2 as $item){
  $decodedItems       = json_decode($item['cart_data'], true);
  $decodedItems['id'] = $item['id'];
  $items[]            = $decodedItems;
}
```

Comment: it says `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: I've added `true` as seconde param in `json_decode` to make it an array.

Comment: Thank you, this works also the one before this `$decodedItems->id` works as well (without true)

Comment: That is also an option. Even better would be using [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections).

Comment: It is a valid answer but i think you need to fix your table structure @mafortis - updating, searching, selecting is/will be painful in this structure. Please check `database normalization`

Comment: @Ersoy if you check [this package](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart) for instance or any other cart package they all use same method as storing cart data into json array, the diffrence is because i am using VueJs I do not have access to sessions on API requests so I've made my own database table version of cart implementation. You might be right but I don't think there is any issue of storing data into json. Also this ID I just need it in order to remove/update items from database, shouldn't actually be in `cart_data` column.